# wordpress media is uploading in wrong folder

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I have a WordPress site. Suddenly I have noticed that when I am uploading my media files through media library, those files are saving in **"uploads/2016/02/"** folder though it is November 2016. But when I am creating posts or pages & adding media files, those files are saving in **"uploads/2016/11/"** folder, which is correct behavior.

N.B.-  media setting (Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders) is checked or enabled.

I have checked the file & directory permissions are ok. I tried with disabling some media related plugin which are installed but nothing worked.

Does anybody have some ideas why media uploader using wrong backdated (Fabruary) folder, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What's the post publish date?

Comment: @Stanimir Stoyanov, Today is 22nd November.If I publish the post today then publish date shows Nov 22, 2016 @ 19:20

Answer (score 5):

Well this is expected behavior. By default WordPress store the media files depending of their post date. You can read more about saving images in [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10752) ticket.

> Using WP 2.8.4, when uploading new media files to a page or post that has already been published, the new file is added in the /UPLOAD_DIR/year/month/ directory that corresponds to the original page/post publication date, rather than the file upload date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my other websites media library saves file according to upload month & year. But here only post related media is uploaded according to upload month & year but using media library files are always uploaded to February folder. I want every time or through every way, files will be uploaded on correct folder. Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I have found previously to resolve this error was done accidentally - rename the upload folder, upload an image and rename the folder again.

Why this fixed it, I'm not sure, I assume it has to do with refreshing the path stored in the database, however it worked for me, so at least this can be seen as worth a try.

Comment: You can also download a new copy of WordPress and overwrite all files, just remember DO NOT COPY the wp-content folder with the fresh download, this should do the job, at least if the problem is with files and not settings...

Comment: Problem has been solved by changing the theme. Thanks for ur help